# Foreign key not updating automatically

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc-5, entity-framework-6

I am using Entity Framework 6 in my MVC 5 project.

This is an example of classes that I have:

```
public class Request
{
    public int RequestID { get; set; }

    public virtual List<File> Files { get; set; }
}

public class File
{
    public int FileID { get; set; }
    public int RequestID { get; set; }

    public virtual Request Request { get; set; }
}
```

The thig is that when I create a File and assign it a Request through the Request property, the RequestID property of the File is not updated with the Request's RequestID.

I thought that this should be something that would be done automatically, correct me if I'm wrong. Or is there something else in my code that would prevent the relation from being done correctly?

EDIT 1

Here's the OnModelCreating function

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>();
    modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<OneToManyCascadeDeleteConvention>();
    base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
}
```

Comment: Can you show us your mapping code in your DbContext OnModelCreating?

Comment: @Jack I added the function.

Answer (score 1):

I believe Entity Framework does now know that the int is the Foreign Key and you need to add something like this in OnModelCreating:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<File>()
            .HasOptional(f => f.Request)
            .WithMany(r => r.Files)
            .HasForeignKey(f => f.RequestId);
```

That should tell EF that the int is the foreign key for that relationship